# $DF(x)$ is invertible. Then is there exists $G:F(R^n) \to R^n$ such that $G(F(x))=x$??

Tags: calculus, analysis

$F:R^n \to R^n$ be continuously differentiable function.

If $DF(x)$ is invertible for every $x \in R^n$. Then there exists $G:F(R^n) \to R^n$ such that $G(F(x))=x$??

Prove or disprove.

Comment: See the answer given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19588/extension-globalization-of-inverse-function-theorem)